# creating mobile application design

Tags: mobile, device

I have this question given to me, and i wanted to get the answer as fast as possible:

Suppose you work for a mobile software development
company. A client wishes for you to build a mobile
application that is designed to assist its network managers in
monitoring the health of its server farm. The target device is
an iPad.

1. Provide sketches of the key interface screens.
2. Provide a storyboard that illustrates the steps of the
   system alerting the network manager about a problem (a
   computer overheating), the network manager investigating the
   details of this problem, and then accessing a map of the server
   farm to find the specific machine.
3. Provide a diagram of the MVC architecture of your
   software.
4. Outline an evaluation plan for ensuring that the
   software fulfils the end-user needs.

what I want to know is :

what is a farm server, what are the things that i could monitor, and what you suggest on me to include in the interface of the mobile application.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this question is pretty complex and the answers may vary, i want to know the answer of this question too.

First thing a server farm: is a place which contains a number of servers that can be monitored remotely.